# Check if property is a child to a parent property

Tags: javascript

I have model of a class-schema. I need to check if a class-name is a instance of class. The reason I do it this way is since I work the data in a webworker and from there I can only get stringified data, hence I cant use `instance of`.

```
var schema = {
  product: {
    buildingElements: {
      pile: null, // last class
      stair: null
    },
    ventilation: {
      duct: null,
      airDevice: null
    }
  }
}

var isClassInstanceOf = function(name, parent, schema){
  ...
}

var a = isClassInstanceOf('duct', 'ventilation', schema); //true
var b = isClassInstanceOf('airDevice', 'buildingElements', schema); // false
var c =  isClassInstanceOf('ventilation', 'product', schema); // true

var e =  isClassInstanceOf('duct', 'product', schema); // true
```

https://jsbin.com/qemunakare/edit?js,output

I don't really know where to begin. Somehow I need to walk the tree with some sort of `while-loop`.

Comment: why `isClassInstanceOf('duct', 'duct', schema)` should give `true`?

Comment: Cause duct is an instance of duct.

Comment: `duct` has `'ventilation'` as a parent, why it is an instance of itself?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest. If I make an instance of the class Duct, the the instansiated object is an instance of duct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an object, you could check for parent objects.

```js
var schema = { product: { buildingElements: { pile: null, stair: null }, ventilation: { duct: null, airDevice: null } } },
    isParentOf = function (name, parent, schema) {
        function search(o, p) {
            return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
                if (k === name) {
                    path = p.concat(k);
                    return true;
                }
                return o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object' && search(o[k], p.concat(k));
            });
        }
        var path = [];
        search(schema, []);
        return path.indexOf(parent) !== -1;
    };

console.log(isParentOf('duct', 'ventilation', schema));           // true
console.log(isParentOf('airDevice', 'buildingElements', schema)); // false
console.log(isParentOf('ventilation', 'product', schema));        // true
console.log(isParentOf('duct', 'duct', schema));                  // true
console.log(isParentOf('duct', 'product', schema));               // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hm. Only worked in one level. Forgot to give example of this in my question.  Any easy way to add so isParentOf('duct', 'product', schema) // true ?

Comment: It needs to be recursive, I would assume.

Comment: @ScottSauyet. Yes. It should simulate a instance-of behaviour.

Comment: it is recursive. please add an object for the test to the question.

Comment: Oh is it. Sorry. Added test to question.

Comment: @PerStröm, do you need all parents in an array and check later?

Comment: @NinaScholz. Array and check later? Don't understand.

Comment: it looks like, you need all parents to check?

Comment: From the "duct"/"duct" relationship, I was assuming that this should be called "ancestor" and not "parent".  That's the sort of recursion I was thinking about.

Comment: @NinaScholz. Yes thats correct. I need all "super-parents" or whatever its called.

Comment: @PerStröm, now in path, you get all parents.

Comment: @NinaScholz. Yes works. Thx. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is nice.  I'm at work and haven't had time to try my idea, but I was thinking of a very different approach:  `ancestors(schema)(parent, child)`, where `ancestors(schema)` calculate some `paths` variable: `{product: ['product'], buildingElement: ['buildingElement', 'product'], pile: ['product', 'buildingElement', 'pile'], stair: ...}`  Then the resulting function would just do an `includes`/`indexOf` test.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are getting your data **object as a string** all you will have to do is `JSON.parse()` this data , then from there you can use `instance of` or `if in` .

Example :

```
var newSchema = JSON.parse(schema);
```

//Now you have a normal javascript object...

**Then:**

**Check for properties...**

```
if('duct' in newSchema['product']['ventilation']) return true;
```

ect...

**Fyi : You should parse objects that are provided as JSON**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Missunderstanding. I instansiate my classes in the webworker. When I'm out of the webworker I need still be able to check the inheritance.

Comment: Once your string data is received in web worker , you will then need to parse it using JSON.parse() .  per your issue :
 ''The reason I do it this way is since I work the data in a webworker and from there I can only get stringified data, hence I cant use instance of."